# Is there a way to add seconds to a SimpleDateFormat object without creating a new object?

Tags: java, date-format

I have my object defined as :

```
DateFormat tf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
```

If I get an input in the format - 10:00 , it throws an exception. Is there a way seconds(:00) could be added automatically to this same object, without having to create a new format as `(HH:mm)` to handle that input separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the input in String format? If so you could use a String and see if it is 5 characters long, and add on the :00.

```
String input = "10:00";
if(input.length() == 5)
{
    input += ":00";
}
```

I'm sure there are better ways of doing this, such as using StringBuilder, but this is a solution if the input is in form of a String.

Comment: What if it is 9:00?  I would split() the string and count the parts before adding the ":00".

Comment: Thank you! Yes the input was as a String so this works.  I'm already handling the input if it is not in the HH format so that is okay! But thank you for bringing that up too!

Comment: Yes I was assuming that it would be 5 characters, such as 09:00. You will have to look into stdunbar's response to handle it otherwise.